# Solr letter transformation / umlauts support

Tags: solr, full-text-search, transformation, diacritics, filterfactory

I'm using Solr 3.x with focus on German text, which works well.
Searching for umlauts (öäüß) also works well.

The problem is:
I received some archived text from the late 80s, were most of the computer/software did not support more than ASCII, especially no German umlauts were supported.
For this an alternative notation was used:

```
ae instead of ä
oe instead of ö
ue instead of ü
ss instead of ß
```

That means, the name `Müller` was saved as `Mueller`.

Back to Solr, I need now to find documents which contains `ue` - even if the user searched for `ü`.

Example: If I like to search for all text messages from the person called `Müller`,
Solr has to find text with `Mueller` and also `Müller`

How can I handle this?

Is this an adequate feature? --> http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UnicodeCollation (I'm not sure, if I understand the documentation completely)

By the way, it's not an option to change the source-text by "search and replace": all `oe` to `ö`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Paige Cook already pointed out, you already found **[the relevant documentation](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UnicodeCollation)**, but since not every Solr user knows Java I decided to create my own answer with a little more detail.

**The first step is to add the filter to your field definition:**

```xml
<fieldType>
  <analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    <!-- BEGIN OF IMPORTANT PART -->
    <filter class="solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory"
        custom="customRules.dat"
        strength="primary"
    />
    <!-- END OF IMPORTANT PART -->
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

**The next step is to create the necessary `customRules.dat` file:**

You have to create a tiny Java program in order to follow the documentation. Unfortunately for non-Java programmers this is a little difficult, since the code snippet only shows the important parts. Also it uses a third-party library not distributed with the JDK (Apache Commons IO)

Heres the full *Java 7* code necessary to write a `customRules.dat` without the use of external libraries:

```java
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class RulesWriter {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RuleBasedCollator baseCollator = (RuleBasedCollator) 
                Collator.getInstance(new Locale("de", "DE"));

        String DIN5007_2_tailorings =
          "& ae , a\u0308 & AE , A\u0308"+
          "& oe , o\u0308 & OE , O\u0308"+
          "& ue , u\u0308 & UE , u\u0308";

        RuleBasedCollator tailoredCollator = new RuleBasedCollator(
                baseCollator.getRules() + DIN5007_2_tailorings);
        String tailoredRules = tailoredCollator.getRules();

        Writer fw = new OutputStreamWriter(
                new FileOutputStream("c:/customRules.dat"), "UTF-8");
        fw.write(tailoredRules);
        fw.flush();
        fw.close();
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer: The above code compiles and creates a `customRules.dat` file, but I didn't actually test the created file with Solr.*

Comment: oh, thank you!! I installed the jdk1.7. Next step: I wrote your text into a file called `RulesWriter.java` and run `javac -RulesWriter.java`. But 6 compiling error occurs, like this: `RulesWriter.java:17: error: unreported exception ParseException; must be caught or declared to be thrown RuleBasedCollator tailoredCollator = new  RuleBasedCollator(...`i have absolutely no idea, what to do. Creating this `customRules.bin` maybe is not the right project for an java-noob like me! :-(

Comment: Argh, I only copied the contents of the main method, not the whole code. Please try again, line 7 was missing a `throws Exception`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the time you have spend in this solution. (+1) creation the `customRules.bin` works very well on an windows PC, running with Java 7. Unfortunately, the (Solr-Linux-)server runs with Java 1.6. Is it possible to use the `customRules.bin` (created with Java 7) on an server with only Java 1.6? I'm asking this question, because `CollationKeyFilterFactory` seams not to work correctly. After activating the `CollationKeyFilterFactory` in SOLR, the analyses.jsp output is like expected (like the example at the documentation), but the search results are SOLR strange....

Comment: I think the Java version doesn't matter, but I didn't actually thought about it until you brought it up. Just in case you want to be sure I modified the code so that it should compile with Java 6. (Removed the usage of Java 7 resource management)

Comment: In an test case with 300.000 documents an search for 'merkel' finds 299521 docs, which doesn't looks like an valid result. An valid result would be something about 1000-2000 docs. If I search for an random string, like 'trasgew', i get 299859 hits, searching for 'dddxxxxxdddddddd' returns 35500 hits - but I'm sure, the last to strings does not exists in any of those 300k docs. So something is going wrong here. It looks like there is an very "strong" fuzzy search?! But I didn't changed the field definition, only added the necessary code, you wrote. Trotzalledem herzlichen Dank & sch[ö|oe]nes WE

Comment: Perhaps adding the `explain` parameter to your query might shed some light on what is going on.

Comment: I added `debugQuery=true` (because `explainOther` is only supported from solr4 - not in Solr 3.x). Probably the point is, how SOLR parsed the query, as you can see on `parsedquery_toString`.
Searching for `merkel` (299521 hits, which never can be valid), the `parsedquery_toString` is
`+(((HEADLINE:0 HEADLINE:倅瀂态㸀)^3.5) | (TOPIC:0 TOPIC:倅瀂态㸀) | ((TEXT:0 TEXT:倅瀂态㸀)^1.5))~0.01 (HEADLINE:"0 倅瀂态㸀"^3.0 | TEXT:"0 倅瀂态㸀"^1.5)~0.01`
while searching for `hotel` (1676 hits, could be valid) the `parsedquery_toString` is
`+(HEADLINE:䀘䀌瀅䀂簀^3.5 | TOPIC:䀘䀌瀅䀂簀 | TEXT:䀘䀌瀅䀂簀^1.5)~0.01 ()`- I can't explain why :-/

Comment: Update: it looks like, the solution is near - the `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` running after the `solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory`seams to be the reason for those multiple hits. changing the order for the analyser: 1st `solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory` 2nd `solr.CollationKeyFilterFactory` seams to solve this problem - i will investigate this next week & and will inform you about the result. At all: Thank you!

Comment: Finally, this Solution works very well. Thank you so much for this great support! :-)

Answer (score 1):

From my interpretation of the link you provided to the Unicode Collation feature, this is the absolute feature as it shows how to solve the **exact same issue** that you are having.

Looks like you will to write a little Java to generate your appropriate customRules.dat file.

Comment: +1 Agreed, that's the solution. (Not so much the Unicode collation but more the custom rules)

Comment: @Daniel Rikowski and Paige Cook: The point is, that I don't understand the documentation at all. I know, I have to add `CollationKeyFilterFactory` to field-definition. But what is the content/syntax of the `customRules.dat`? I don't know anything about Java Code - I use Lucene in combination with Solr and PHP :-/

Comment: @The Bndr: The format is described at http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/RuleBasedCollator.html, but that doesn't help you, because creating the full file from scratch would be a lot of error-prone work. I've added an own answer including *working* code to create the file yourself. (Still, you'll need to get your hands dirty with Java)